# How can I change the time in a $query

Tags: mysql

I know nothing of coding and have a site where if a reservation is more than 6 minutes old it is deleted. I have looked through the files and found this.

```
$query = "DELETE 
          FROM $table_app 
          WHERE status = 'reservation' AND created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MINUTE)";
```

If I change the interval time in this line will it work or is the time taken from somewhere else. If this is the time can I change the units to HOURS OR DAYS. I need to stop the reservation being automatically deleted for at least 6 months.

Comment: Where is the jQuery in this? Looks like sql. Just because jQuery has the word query as part of it, please read the tag description before using it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: For example have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=created+NOW+INTERVAL+mysql+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Do you want the rows older than 6 months to be deleted from the table automatically, without any application execution? If so then use [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Comment: I would question the wisdom of executing a hard delete in application code

Comment: I have entered 1000 MINUTES which appeared to have worked is there a maximum value or can I enter 1000000 ?